# ReadDirectoryChangesW all actions

Tags: python, winapi, readdirectorychangesw

I'm using the code of Tim Golden to read directory changes (http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html)
using the ReadDirectoryChangesW function.
In his code, there is a Enum that include 5 types of action that the function ReadDirectoryChangesW return:
  1 : "Created",
  2 : "Deleted",
  3 : "Updated",
  4 : "Renamed from something",
  5 : "Renamed to something"

I wonder if there is more options to Add for this Enum.
I want to see if there was change in the file size, Change in Atrributes, and in this code the both are "Updated" Enum.. but i want to get a diffrent int from the function for each update.
Also, if there is more values that the function returns, i would like to see that too!
Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation and answer the question yourself. Does ReadDirectoryChangesW offer that information?

Comment: You might consider using the USN journal instead, which provides [considerably more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365722(v=vs.85).aspx).  It's a lot more work to use, though, and you need admin privilege.

Comment: I search in the ReadDirectoryChangesW documentation and before I went to stackoverflow, there is "win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |" and 
" win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES" but both of them included in the int 3.
I could not find it alone so i came to here. Can you help me ? please//
@DavidHeffernan

Comment: If its need admin privilege its not good for me, the program need to run on any computer for amy user.. 
The "ReadDircetoryChanfgesW" provides only the 5 action that there is in the Enum of the code in my Main message?
@HarryJohnston

Comment: The documentation has the answers. The API doesn't give you the granularity that you want. That can be deduced by reading the documentation I think you needed to go over it again.

Comment: The `win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE` and `win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES` are for use with `FindFirstChangeNotification` not `ReadDirectoryChangesW`.

Comment: "Updated" covers all changes including size, timestamp and attributes. If you want to know what changed you have to remember and compare with the previous values.